# Async Errors in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, schedule, telethon

I'm coding a telegram userbot (with telethon) which sends a message,every 60 seconds, to some chats.

I'm using 2 threads but I get the following errors: "*RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sender' was never awaited*" and "*no running event loop*".

**My code**:

```
....

async def sender():
    for chat in chats :
        try:
            if  chat.megagroup == True:
                await client.send_message(chat, messaggio)
        except:
            await client.send_message(myID, 'error')
schedule.every(60).seconds.do(asyncio.create_task(sender()))

...
class checker1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
class checker2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            client.add_event_handler(handler)
            client.run_until_disconnected()
checker2().start()
checker1().start()
```

I searched for a solution but I didn't find anything...

Comment: Exactly: where is `sender` awaited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using threads with `asyncio` unless you know what you're doing. The code can be rewritten using `asyncio` as follows, since most of the time you don't actually need threads:

```py
import asyncio

async def sender():
    for chat in chats :
        try:
            if  chat.megagroup == True:
                await client.send_message(chat, messaggio)
        except:
            await client.send_message(myID, 'error')

async def checker1():
    while True:
        await sender()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # every 60s

async def main():
    await asyncio.create_task(checker1())  # background task
    await client.run_until_disconnected() 

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This code is not perfect (you should properly cancel and wait `checker1` at the end of the program), but it should work.

As a side note, you don't *need* `client.run_until_disconnected()`. The call simply blocks (runs) until the client is disconnected. If you can keep the program running differently, as long as `asyncio` runs, the `client` will work.

Another thing: bare `except:` are a very bad idea, and will probably cause issues with exception. At least, replace it with `except Exception`.

Comment: I do appreciate your help! You've been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. `asyncio` is complaining about "no running event loop" because your program never starts the event loop anywhere, and tasks can't be scheduled without an event loop running. See [Asyncio in corroutine RuntimeError: no running event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774718/asyncio-in-corroutine-runtimeerror-no-running-event-loop). In order to start the event loop, you can use `asyncio.run_until_complete()` if you have a main coroutine for your program, or you can use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()` to run the event loop forever.

The second problem is the incorrect usage of `schedule.every(60).seconds.do()`, which is hidden by the first error. `schedule` expects a *function* to be passed in, not an awaitable (which is what `asyncio.create_task(sender())` returns). This normally would have caused a `TypeError`, but the `create_task()` without a running event loop raised an exception first, so this exception was never raised. You'll need to define a function and then pass it to `schedule`, like this:

```py
def start_sender():
    asyncio.create_task(sender())
schedule.every(60).seconds.do(start_sender)
```

This should work as long as the event loop is started somewhere else in your program.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I upgraded my  code:  def start_sender():
    print("done")
    asyncio.create_task(sender())
schedule.every(60).seconds.do(start_sender) 
... asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
checker2().start()
checker1().start() -> but now looks like the thread checker1 doesn't work (even though no errors appear in the console)

Comment: @maic0L `run_forever()` is a *blocking call*, meaning that it won't exit until it finishes (through something else calling `stop()`). This unfortunately means that any code after it will not run until it exits, which causes the `start()` calls to never be executed. Try moving the `run_forever()` call to the end of your program.